# a verbal phrase between two commas without any conjunction! Is it grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

What is the role of the phrase "**may lead to weight gain**" in the following sentence? Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> Long hours spent reading and writing are not conducive to good
> posture, **may lead to weight gain**, and may result in anxiety and stress
> via overwork.

Comment: While the sentence appears grammatically correct to me, I am unsure how to answer the question otherwise. I will GUESS that "may lead to weight gain" is an adverb clause. Haven't time to research atm, but this might help someone answer.

Comment: @CorvusB No: it's not an adverb clause but a verb phrase. "Long hours spent reading and writing are [not conducive to good posture], [not conducive to good posture], [may lead to weight gain], and [may result in anxiety and stress via overwork]. The bracketed expressions form a coordination of VPs.

Comment: @BillJ OP asked about the role of the VP. What is its function? I know it's part of a predicate - [[VP1], [VP2] and [VP3]] = PREDICATE?

Comment: @Man_From_India Yes: the coordination of VPs functions as the predicate of the whole sentence, with "long hours spent reading and writing" as subject.

Comment: Thank you @BillJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. It's the second item in a list. Only the last item in a list requires a conjunction. Any part of speech, including verb phrases, can be in a list.

A more clear-cut example:

> Most evenings, I play hockey, **ride my bike**, and walk the dog.

Comment: So, as per BillJ's comments previously, we have a list of verb phrases.

Comment: @CorvusB Ah, true. There's an error in BillJ's comment: the implication of "... **are may** lead to weight gain ... and **are may** result" by how he bracketed the list items. It looks like it's likely due to cut-n-pasting while composing it, but I stopped reading when I saw it